# Runtime error, program returns nothing and doesn't stop running

Tags: c#, recursion

```
class DigitalRoots
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a non-negative integer: ");
        int numbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine(DigitalRoot(numbers));
        Console.WriteLine(Recursion(numbers));
    }

    static int DigitalRoot(int num)
    {
        if (num < 10)
        {
            return num;
        }
        else
        {
            int sum = 0;

            while (num > 0)
            {
                sum += num % 10;
                num = num / 10; 
            }

            return DigitalRoot(sum);
        }
    }

    static int Recursion(int num)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        string str = Convert.ToString(num);

        while(str.Length > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++){
                sum += Convert.ToInt32(str[i]);
            }
            str = Convert.ToString(sum);
        } 

        int result = Convert.ToInt32(str);
        return Recursion(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: What are your inputs?

Comment: No, i've not debug
Console.WriteLine(DigitalRoot(numbers));
Console.WriteLine(Recursion(numbers));

Comment: I guess you want to explore recursion, right? You know you can do `int DigitalRoot(int num) => num % 9;` instead of the recursion?

Comment: Digital Root method works fine.....But the recursion method not working

Comment: Yes, scrap it. Whatever it does. It shouldn't go from string to int and back in high frequency. Even once would lift an eyebrowe with me.

Comment: ^^ That said, I just realized your `Recursion` method implements the algorithm iteratively and _then_ goes into infinite recursion. Which is a bit hard to see at first glance, because of all those conversions.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Recursion`-method lacks an exit condition. So it will just continue to call itself until you get a stack overflow, or run out of memory or some other resource.

All recursive method need an exit condition, usually in the beginning of the method, for example something like

```
if (num > 0) return num;
```

And you need to ensure this condition is eventually reached, ideally before you run out of stack.

Note that I have no idea what the code is actually supposed to do, but this is probably not the best way to do it. In general it is often a good idea to prefer iterative solutions when possible.

Comment: It seems like OP tried to make two versions for the same algorithm, not realizing the second approach already implements the algorithm iteratively just to go full recurse with the result.

Comment: Yes, i am trying two versions for the same algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down:

```
static int Recursion(int num) // assume input '99'
{
    int sum = 0;
    string str = Convert.ToString(num); // '99' => "99"

    while(str.Length > 1) // "99".Length = 2 , "18".Length = 2, "9".Length = 1
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++){
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(str[i]);   
//1.while:
// i=0(9): sum = 9, i=1(9): sum = 18 
//2.while:
// i=0(1): sum = 1, i=1(8): sum = 9 
        }
        str = Convert.ToString(sum);
// 1.while: str = "18"
// 2. while str = "9"
    } 

    int result = Convert.ToInt32(str); // result = '9'
    return Recursion(result); // Infinite recursion
    // with '9' as input, the while loop is never entered.
    // which means input becomes unaltered new input to next recursion ...
}
```

Now you could ...

- Fix the recursion

by introducing a stopping condition, for example `return (result<10) ? result : Recursion(result);`

- Ditch the recursion

Because your code already solves the problem iteratively.

- Use the numeric-only version, which is working as expected. And I'd always prefer a numeric-only solution for a numeric problem.
- Use a closed expression instead ( f(n) = n%9 ). Which I'd prefer even over an iterative numeric-only solution if it exists.

Comment: I barely understand the part introducing a stopping condition, for example return (result<10) ? result : Recursion(result);

Comment: It's a ternary expression. It means if result is less than 10 return it, otherwise return the result of the recursive call.